# adding custom jQuery to wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I have read a number of tutorials on adding jQuery to a Wordpress template and it's very difficult as they aren't specific at times with what steps to take to load your custom jQuery.
I'm new to this whole Wordpress thing and I've gotten as far as adding the following to functions.php

```
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_my_script' );
function add_my_script() {
wp_enqueue_script(
    'toggle-script',
    get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/toggle-script.js', 
    array('jquery')
);
}
```

and then adding my toggle-script.js to the js folder within my template directory.

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(".title").click(function(){
    $(this).siblings(".location").slideToggle();
    });
```

However, once it's all added, it breaks my slider plugin (which presumably is using a javascript library that gets overwritten during the functions.php step) I have on the front page but still doesn't allow for the toggle function to work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: there should be no issues with the code that you've posted. two things: 1. can we see the error generated, and 2. can you try passing 2 more arguments to `wp_enqueue_script` which are `, null, true);`

Comment: Note that your JS is missing another one of `});`.

Comment: there is no error message generated. It's just a blank space on my front page which should be showing a slider.

Answer (score 0):

Add `wp_head` before the `</head>` tag if it is missing.